# Does routing distance affect performance significantly?

Tags: hosting, latency, networking

When I say routing distance, I mean on a global scale. For instance, if my target audience is in China, do I look for a host within China?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/61719/how-does-geography-affect-network-latency

Comment: dup yes, but this one has the answer with the cool graphics VVVV

Comment: I so wish I could see the pretty graphics that got deleted ;-(

Comment: I updated the links to the photos - you should be able to see them again now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The Short Answer

Yes

---

### The Long Answer

It may not necessarily need to be right in the country you are targeting - just a close region could be sufficient.

A good start is to determine where the major internet backbones/intercontinental links are in relation to your target audience, and plan accordingly.  This way you could position services in a more advantageous position for future expansion.  You can also choose to locate in *adjacent* countries that have lower hosting costs.

You can do this with [maps](http://www.telegeography.com/maps/index.php) such as this:

[Regional Internet Map http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_traffic/images/inset.gif](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_traffic/images/inset.gif)
[Global Internet Map http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/internet_map09_sm.gif](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/internet_map09_sm.gif)
[image: Regional Internet Map]
<sub>(source: [telegeography.com](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/internet_map_2010_sm.png))</sub>

[blah http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/im09_europe.gif](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/im09_europe.gif)
[blah http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/main-projection-2010.png](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_internet/images/main-projection-2010.png)

Comment: brilliant. just brillaint.

Comment: They are rather pretty aren't they :)

Comment: Have these maps become paid for content? Images are currently broken. Is there another source?

Answer (score 4):

If your target audience is *actually* china, then you have other problems to worry about, due to their extensive fire walling of traffic, if your application uses anything but port 80, with a fairly standard traffic pattern, then it will likely be blocked.

Where ever you host you may want to run a series of tests (latency, bandwidth, reliability) to and from the networks where your user base resides.

Ask your host for monitoring logs , if they cant or wont provide it, don't even consider them.

Don't be fooled by marketing hype, get to talk to a techie and see what level of global transit they have, the number of private peering points they have.

Also, worry about the speed of light, if your hosting on the other side of the world, your latency will be pretty bad, and you'll more than likely feel the full force of any global routing problems that occur.